# Most efficient method for "tiling" a smaller 2d array in a larger 2d array in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, multidimensional-array

If I have a 2d array such as

```
smallArray = [[1,0],[0,1]]
```

and I have a larger 2d array such as

```
largeArray = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
```

What would be the most efficient way to "tile" the smaller array in the bigger one so that the bigger array would end up looking like

```
largeArray = [[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1]]
```

A complicated sequence of for loops?

Answer (score 2):

In AS3,an array doesn't care what the types of its elements are, right?  Why not just  largeArray.push(smallArrayN).  And if efficiency is a consideration, you should probably be using vectors, as they are like arrays only extremely faster.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it requires nested for-loop because you are merging small array elements to large array recursively. When each element is updated in array , we use loops or nested loops.